# Result set with multiplied rows into an SSRS report

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to get this query into an SSRS report.

```
SELECT  s.SR_Service_RecID    -- will have 1 result
     ,  p.Description         -- will have 8 results 
     ,  t.notes               -- will have 5 results

FROM SR_Service s
     LEFT JOIN IV_Product p
            ON p.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID
     LEFT JOIN Time_Entry t
            ON t.SR_Service_RecID = s.SR_Service_RecID
```

This query is multiplying p.Description by t.Notes for the total number of rows as expected.

Result set:

```
SR_RecID    Description    Notes
12345       Product 1      Note 1
12345       Product 1      Note 2
12345       Product 1      Note 3
12345       Product 1      Note 4
12345       Product 1      Note 5
12345       Product 2      Note 1
12345       Product 2      Note 2
12345       Product 2      Note 3
12345       Product 2      Note 4
12345       Product 2      Note 5
Etc..
```

How can this be put into an SSRS report so it displays only the actual results, not the multiplied amounts?

```
SR_RecID
12345

Description
Product 1
Product 2
Product 3
Product 4
Product 5
Product 6
Product 7
Product 8

Notes 1
Notes 2
Notes 3
Notes 4
Notes 5
```

Do I need to rework the query or can this be done on the SSRS end of things?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve this by adding tablix:

[image: image1]

and using 3 adjacent groups (grouped by each field) like follows:

[image: image2]

You will get this result:

[image: image3]

Comment: It's a good solution, the only problem is in case he's got more than one `SR_RecID`, which I think is the case. Being that you would need to put `SR_RecID` as an outer group and inside you can add `Description` and `Notes`

Comment: Yes in that case you a right, but in the question moment with output format wasn't fully clear for me.

Comment: This worked beautifully. Thanks very much! For the record it was multiple SR_RecIDs so I created the outer group.